# app crashing when changing or editing the event location in EKEventEditViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

im trying to add events from my app to my calendar, when i display the  EKEventEditViewController , and try to set or edit the location manually by keyboard, the app is crashing and giving the error :Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9.

```
- (void)createEventAndPresentViewController:(EKEventStore *)store
{
        EKEvent *event = [self findOrCreateEvent:store];
        //EKEvent *event = [self createEvent:store];
        EKEventEditViewController *controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
        controller.event = event;
        controller.eventStore = store;
        controller.editViewDelegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (EKEvent *)findOrCreateEvent:(EKEventStore *)store {
.
.
.
}
```

Any idea what the problem could be?
thanks

Comment: interesting, it is also happening to me in Swift. I wonder what we're missing?

Comment: i have figured out the error, you should add permissions:contact usage description,calendar usage description, reminders usage description